# Delay Showing Next Field After Typing Is Complete (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to not overwhelm users with all the fields that I want filled out by showing them the next field only once they've filled out the previous field. I used the keyup event but that's not the best user experience. I'd like to wait 1 second after the user is done typing to then show the next field. Here's the code I have so far.

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup change', '[id*="fieldname"]', function(){ 
var id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 

if(/fieldname2_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname3_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname3_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname4_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname4_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname6_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname6_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname5_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname5_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname7_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname1_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname24_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname10_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname12_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname29_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname42_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname43_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname35_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname37_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
if(/fieldname7_/.test(id)) jQuery('[id*="fieldname44_"]').closest('.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
}); 
</script>
```

I was also trying to add some time by using this event but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup(_.debounce(doSomething , 100)) change', '[id*="fieldname"]', function(){ 
var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
```

Any ideas on how I could wait 1 second after they have finished typing to show the next field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```js
var timer;
var hiddenArray=[];
for(i=0;i<$(".hidden").length;i++){
  hiddenArray.push($(".hidden").eq(i));
}

$("input").on("keyup",function(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  if($(this).val()!=""){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){

      for(i=0;i<hiddenArray.length;i++){
        if(hiddenArray[i].hasClass("hidden")){
          hiddenArray[i].removeClass("hidden").find("input").focus();
          return;
        }
      }
    },1000);  // 1 second delay
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Field #1: <input type="text" id="fieldname1">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #2: <input type="text" id="fieldname2">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #3: <input type="text" id="fieldname3">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #4: <input type="text" id="fieldname4">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #5: <input type="text" id="fieldname5">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #6: <input type="text" id="fieldname6">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #7: <input type="text" id="fieldname7">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #8: <input type="text" id="fieldname8">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #9: <input type="text" id="fieldname9">
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  Field #10: <input type="text" id="fieldname10">
</div>
```

It uses an array to loop throught hidden elements and a timer which resets itself on keyup, executing the function only if the delay has been consumed.

---

## EDIT

Looking again at your code in question.

For your "special input order"...
A [`.match()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) could be used, using [`regex`](https://regex101.com/#javascript)...
With a [`switch()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) instead of too many same-like `if`.

*Assuming the `input` are numbered sequentially in the HTML.*

```
var timer;
var inputArray=[];
for(i=0;i<$("[id*='fieldname']").length;i++){
  inputArray.push( $("[id*='fieldname']").eq(i) );
  //console.log( inputArray[i].attr("id") );
}

$(document).on("keyup", "[id*='fieldname']", function(e){
  clearTimeout(timer);

  var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log( "$(this): #"+ thisId );

  if($(this).val()!=""){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      //console.log("timer end");

      var thisInputNumber = parseInt( thisId.match( /\D(\d+).+/ )[1] );
      console.log( thisInputNumber );

      switch(thisInputNumber){

          // Special cases.
        case 4:
          var ToUnhide = 6
          inputArray[ToUnhide-1].parents(".tablerow").show().find("input").focus();
          break;

        case 5:
          var ToUnhide = 7
          inputArray[ToUnhide-1].parents(".tablerow").show().find("input").focus();
          break;

        case 6:
          var ToUnhide = 5
          inputArray[ToUnhide-1].parents(".tablerow").show().find("input").focus();
          break;

        case 7:
          // List of input ids to unhide.
          var ToUnhide=[1,24,10,12,29,42,43,35,37,44];
          // Unhide all these input ids.
          for(k=0;k<ToUnhide.length;k++){
            inputArray[ToUnhide[k]-1].parents(".tablerow").show().find("input").focus();
          }
          break;

        default:
          console.log("default case");
          inputArray[thisInputNumber].parents(".tablerow").show().find("input").focus();
          break;
                            }
    },1000);  // 1 second delay
  }
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jwaJQw?editors=1111)

Comment: Thanks Louys. I think this will work but I have a question about the if statements I had in my original doc. The fields that I want to show next are dependent on the field that has been filled. How do I define which field to show next in the code example you sent? Sorry for the basic question but I'm not a developer, just trying to hack my way through a solution that works for my page (https://getpaidup.com/newsite/price-calculator) that I build in WordPress. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure to get the question... But to acces a children element in the unhide loop, I've made it with `.focus()`. To access the previous element, it could be `hiddenArray[i-1].find("input").val()`...

Comment: I had a second look at your code... And played *quite long* with a CodePen. You should have all you need with this **edit**.

Comment: Thanks fo the accept... That is cool code... You how owe a beer. ;)